# Color hint when selected

Tags: android

I have the login page with 2 editText.
The code of one of them is (the other is similar:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

            android:id="@+id/id2"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textInputLayout"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textInputLayout"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textInputLayout"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@xml/my_border"
            android:gravity="bottom|left|center_horizontal"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:textColorHint="@color/pantoneC10">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="59dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@xml/my_border"
                android:gravity="bottom|left|center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:shadowColor="@color/pantoneC10"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColorHighlight="@color/pantoneC10"
                android:textColorHint="@color/pantoneC10"
                android:textColorLink="@color/pantoneC10"
                android:textSelectHandle="@color/pantoneC10" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

When I select a EditText to type, the color of hint is bordeux. I want it blue. How can I do? 
Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to be blue even when there is no text or only when it is selected/has some text? If you need it always then the link given by @Bob solves your prob

Comment: Thank you! Solved!